# Facebook Chat "seen"

Tags: facebook

Does the 'seen' thing work even if you aren't on at the same time?

For example: if person "A" sends a message to person "B" but person "B" wasn't on that time, then person "A" logs off. Then Person "B" logs back in and sees the message and logs off. When person "A" logs on again, would person "A" see the "seen at..." thing or not?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The information is posted asynchronously to Facebook's servers as a "message read status", and will be stored until person A logs in again.

There is a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gfjpoahaombpolfifdahikhbdnjjeifk/) to disable this new "seen" feature on facebook.